# Update or add new element to array of objects and update array in object if value exists

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm currently trying to build an `addOrUpdate function`.
Unfortunately I failed several times.

Basically, I have an array of objects. Each object in turn has an `array of strings`     `values` (and a key `valueGroup`).

**First you have to check if the object exists, if not a new one should be added. If the object already exists, I want to check whether the value I want to insert is already in the object's string array. If not add it. Is it there delete it!**

I first tried it functionally via mapper, but I failed completely because I got a double array. Of course, it would be best to solve it completely functionally. Is it possible?

Currently there is no update of the objects. A new object is always inserted, again with an array string containing a new value.

I also find the current code too complicated

I am using Typescript

```
type SelectedValues = {
    valueGroup: string;
    values: string[];
};

function updateSelectedValues(selectedValues: SelectedValues[], valueGroup: string, value: string): SelectedValues[] {
    // If array empty add first object
    if (selectedValues.length === 0) {
        return [{ valueGroup: valueGroup, values: [value] }];
    } else {
        // look if valueGroup is already there
        const index = selectedValues.findIndex((find) => find.valueGroup === valueGroup);
        if (index === -1) {
            // if no add new valueGroup with first values
            return [...selectedValues, { valueGroup: valueGroup, values: [value] }];
        } else {
            // if valueGroup is there, look if value is already in values
            const findedValues = selectedValues[index];
            if (findedValues.values.includes(value)) {
                // yes, remove value from values
                return [...selectedValues, { ...findedValues, values: findedValues.values.filter((filter) => filter !== value) }];
            } else {
                // no, add value to values
                return [
                    ...selectedValues.filter((object) => object.valueGroup === valueGroup),
                    { ...findedValues, values: [...findedValues.valueGroup, value] },
                ];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I always click a button. The button passes the values `(valueGroup and value)` ​​through the OnClick handler. The array should update itself according to my explanation. Here is an example of how that array could change

```
//Imagine, after some time we are here. At first it was empty. Two groups were inserted and filled

        type SelectedValues = [
            {
            valueGroup: "valueGroupOne",
            values: ["some", "more", "example", ]
            }, 
            {
            valueGroup: "valueGroupTwo",
            values: ["ddd", "sss", "aaa", ]
            }
            ]
     
    // And new group 
    
     type SelectedValues = [
            {
            valueGroup: "valueGroupOne",
            values: ["some", "more", "example", ]
            }, 
            {
            valueGroup: "valueGroupTwo",
            values: ["ddd", "sss", "aaa", ]
            },
             valueGroup: "valueGroupThree",
            values: ["ssss", "dddsd", "adsdas", ]
            }
            ]
    
    // add to an existing Group new value
    
     type SelectedValues = [
            {
            valueGroup: "valueGroupOne",
            values: ["some", "more", "example","newValueadded" ]
            }, 
            {
            valueGroup: "valueGroupTwo",
            values: ["ddd", "sss", "aaa", ]
            },
             valueGroup: "valueGroupThree",
            values: ["ssss", "dddsd", "adsdas", ]
            }
            ]
    
    // delete from existing Group value
    
     type SelectedValues = [
            {
            valueGroup: "valueGroupOne",
            values: ["some", "more", "example" ]
            }, 
            {
            valueGroup: "valueGroupTwo",
            values: ["ddd", "sss", "aaa", ]
            },
             valueGroup: "valueGroupThree",
            values: ["ssss", "dddsd", "adsdas", ]
            }
            ]
```

Comment: Can you share the original array you try to edit, then we can reproduce your issu and try to fix it ;)

Comment: It is an empty array from the beginning. Or what do you mean? :)

Comment: @nem0z SelectedValues is the type. Does that help?

Comment: Ok well can you should the format this array should have ? For exemple fill it with a random data

Comment: yes sure. One second please

Comment: @nem0z should I maybe post 5-8 steps so that it is understandable?

Comment: @nem0z I added three steps. Hope thats helps! thx

Comment: I think the logic for the very first steps is understandable.It's basically the same, just with an empty array that I'm slowly filling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were already pretty close, just made some small errors like not filtering out the object you want to update from the array. I did also change it to use `find` instead of `findIndex` but it does not make a huge difference.

```
function updateSelectedValues(selectedValues: SelectedValues[], valueGroup: string, value: string): SelectedValues[] {
    // If array empty add first object
    if (selectedValues.length === 0) {
        return [{ valueGroup: valueGroup, values: [value] }];
    } else {
        // look if valueGroup is already there
        const obj = selectedValues.find((find) => find.valueGroup === valueGroup);
        if (!obj) {
            // if no add new valueGroup with first values
            return [...selectedValues, { valueGroup: valueGroup, values: [value] }];
        } else {
            if (obj.values.includes(value)) {
                // yes, remove value from values
                return [...selectedValues.filter((object) => object.valueGroup !== valueGroup), { ...obj, values: obj.values.filter((filter) => filter !== value) }];
            } else {
                // no, add value to values
                return [
                    ...selectedValues.filter((object) => object.valueGroup !== valueGroup),
                    { ...obj, values: [...obj.values, value] },
                ];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above shows where you went wrong in your implementation. However we could simplify it to be this:

```
function updateSelectedValuesLight(selectedValues: SelectedValues[], valueGroup: string, value: string): SelectedValues[] {
    const obj = selectedValues.find((value) => value.valueGroup === valueGroup);

    if (!obj) return [...selectedValues, {valueGroup, values: [value]}]; 

    if (obj.values.includes(value)) {
        obj.values = [...obj.values.filter(iValue => iValue !== value)];
    } else {
        obj.values = [...obj.values, value];
    }

    return selectedValues;
}
```

This [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-HgqGYjLJ0VZHI7KGjz11ksO2s+ZRdUBrZO9624Ufem1GLYsjIXra7nMXlkHAripyBoozgLBIfL8uaKvS2OG7ygwFVc5PFuuVZtD4zNbrSTWhCbG-bs07JDdv+vZumiW7DkKo6vmGjwTrMU7xLadqzs62oAqoqTQecAYHqo5Z4eceF4c4rjuJ43hgL4-hUg2hAADL8MIuzAMsjrUtOCRsbRdRKAhnwlPIBTagJ+QVJx9ZfjxkLUMSJgmmSFIfk6NLMoyKaAdqfYotk-IQdkIoUAsEbSrMpyVtaSG1jRkkuqBXymr6cRKHuUCGecEYoTScYJkmKZpvKnnrBSlmBd+K5LvwX4aZFcRQOBKY4dQQbgtAoZQqFRCkCFsxaTmaH7klbk0OZXhKexhBqIZskTHOAAaFI+H4EBVJ+tQMUxLFpFAABEuz8N16TdagvDdQZ1WsIgWysMIYTdZe6ADaatVjSSJqNTE9WkOtzXWW1jHMcmtS1YNfWLUNhDAAATKN4jjZNsIzd121oItz3LbdJITRAU2PdteoGvseYFhAr2UU1LXKes7UHW9J39YNw3AKNK0mF9P2zZeyqalAwhCqDVE7VxknQyxsM9VM2ZnYjyP7oZEhAA) has some tests to see the functionality.

Comment: Ok. Three Minutes please :)

Comment: Awesome. It is working good praise you! –

Comment: It's not possible to refactor that somehow, is it? to make it nicer?

Comment: it is, i can add it to my answer. I wanted to show with your code where you went wrong

Comment: it is added now, with an updated playground.

Comment: hmm the values array is not updating. It is staying by one value all the time

Comment: where are you testing it? in the playground it works. i did change the function name to  `...Light` for the playground. make sure you factor this in.

Comment: I am so confused. Your code seems perfect. Why is the value array not updating in my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246491/discussion-between-dean-and-maxfromgermany).

Comment: Hey Dean, I finally figured out why your function wasn't working. Basically because of that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73032428/react-context-is-calling-my-reducer-two-times-on-every-dispatch?noredirect=1#comment128989710_73032428
The first answer, solves the problem almost immediately. The problem is that somehow your functional function stores the values ​​in the find method and then removes them on the second run. 
Do you know why? I don't even know if react is your specialty

Comment: The first solution works

Comment: replied in chat

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the help of few JavaScript methods **:**

- [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) - Used to check if object exist or not based on the key.
- [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) - Used to iterate the original array to add/update the value.
- [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) - Used to check if values array contains the value which we want to insert or not.
- [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) - Used to remove the value if exist.
- [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) - Used to push the value in values array if not exist / push the object itself if not exist.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const arr = [{
  valueGroup: 'Group 1',
  values: ['Value 1', 'Value 2']
}, {
  valueGroup: 'Group 2',
  values: ['Value 3', 'Value 4']
}, {
  valueGroup: 'Group 3',
  values: ['Value 5', 'Value 6']
}];

function updateSelectedValues(inputArr, valueGroup, value) {
  const objectExist = inputArr.some(obj => obj.valueGroup === valueGroup);
  if (objectExist) {
    inputArr.forEach(obj => {
      if (obj.valueGroup === valueGroup) {
        obj.values.includes(value) ?
          obj.values.splice(obj.values.indexOf(value), 1) : obj.values.push(value)
      }
    })
  } else {
    arr.push({
      valueGroup: valueGroup,
      values: [value]
    });
  }
  return arr;
}

const result = updateSelectedValues(arr, 'Group 2', 'Value 4');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: hmm the values string array are not updating, if I put the logic in my function

Comment: @maxfromgermany Are you getting any errors ? Is your `searchObj` containing the same format as mine ?

Comment: I am not sure yet, if it is important, but these are the paramters of my funtction: (selectedValues: SelectedValues[], valueGroup: string, value: string) you are using the whole object

Comment: what should I return, if I put your code in my function?

Comment: Your code, is going to work, with my situation. Your types are wrong

Comment: @maxfromgermany Now I got the idea what you actually want. I updated my answer and it is working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function that takes 2 parameters (array with SelectedValues && object with data to add/edit/remove) :

let data = [{
valueGroup: "valueGroupOne",
values: ["some", "more", "example", ]
},
{
valueGroup: "valueGroupTwo",
values: ["ddd", "sss", "aaa", ]
}
];

```
function addOrEdit(arr, valueGroup, value) {
    arr = [...arr];
    let valueGroupIdx = arr.findIndex(el => el.valueGroup == valueGroup);

    if(valueGroupIdx > -1) {
        if(arr.at(valueGroupIdx).values.includes(value)) {
            arr[valueGroupIdx].values.splice(arr[valueGroupIdx].values.indexOf(value), 1)
        } else {
            arr[valueGroupIdx].values.push(value)
        } 

    } else {
        arr.push({
            'valueGroup': valueGroup,
            'values': [value],
        });
    }

    return arr;
}

data = addOrEdit(data, 'valueGroupTwo', 'sss');
data = addOrEdit(data, 'valueGroupTwo', 'aaa');
data = addOrEdit(data, 'valueGroupTwo', 'test');
data = addOrEdit(data, 'valueGroupThree', 'one');
data = addOrEdit(data, 'valueGroupThree', 'two');
data = addOrEdit(data, 'valueGroupThree', 'one');


console.log(data);
```

Comment: Ok Will try that out.3 minues please

Comment: I am not sure yet, if it is important, but these are the paramters of my funtction: `(selectedValues: SelectedValues[], valueGroup: string, value: string)` you are using the whole object

Comment: I will try this out as well. One sec please

Comment: In your post. Is values a string[] ?

Comment: Yes it is an array of strings

Comment: But it can be anything else inside the array (exepted object / array)

Comment: It should be a string

Comment: I don't use TypeScript but if you want you can restrict it to string[] and it will works

Comment: your idea is based on `value` being an array

Comment: I cant do that in my code `!values.includes(v)` cause value not values need to bee a string

Comment: Ok, I miss understood the probleme, I edited my code, now value is a simple string ;)

Comment: hmmm I dont see the problem. But the values array is emty all the time

Comment: hmm, I believe you. You are make return arr at the end or?

Comment: It doesn't return, it edit `arr` but for sure you can add `return arr`at the end. just note that it will change the logic outside the function as you will need to store the new value in a variable each time you call `addOrEdit`

Comment: I need to return it. Is that important? So i need to return the updated array

Comment: I just edied ;)

Comment: Somehow that part is just not working  arr[valueGroupIdx].values.push(value)

Comment: Which error does it throw ?

Comment: It is not an error. The value string[] is not updating

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246492/discussion-between-maxfromgermany-and-nem0z).