# React Context Cannot update a component while rendering a different component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, use-context, use-reducer

I discovered that my `reducer` was being called twice for each `dispatch` after noticing that some of my code's functionality was broken. Now I found out that it is due to the `<StrictMode>`. I would hate to remove this. If I turn on my debugger (StrictMode still there), I get this error

```
  Cannot update a component (`ForwardRef(TouchRipple)`) while rendering a different component
```

As you can see, I build my provider according to the `reducer-dispatch pattern`

*I'm posting the code, with very simple naming.*

types

```
export type ValueState = {
    value: string | null;
};


export enum AcionType {
    SetValue,
}
export interface SetValue {
    type: AcionType.SetValue;
    value: string | null;
}

export type ValueActions = SetValue;

export type ValueDispatch = Dispatch<ValueActions>;

export type ValueContextState = {
    state: ValueState;
    dispatch: ValueDispatch;
};
```

reducer

```
export const valueReducer = (state: ValueState, action: ValueActions): ValueState => {
    console.log("reducer") // getting called two times!!;
    switch (action.type) {
        case AcionType.SetValue:
            return {
                ...state,
                value: test(action.value),
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
const test = (value: string | null) => {
    debugger;
    return value;
};
```

Context

```
export const ValueContext = createContext<ValueContextState>({
    state: getDefaultState(),
    dispatch: () => {},
});

    export const ValueProvider = ({ children }: Props) => {
        const [state, dispatch] = useReducer<React.Reducer<ValueState, ValueActions>>(valueReducer, getDefaultState());
    
        const [contextValue, setContextValue] = useState<ValueContextState>({
            state,
            dispatch,
        });
    

        useEffect(() => {
            setContextValue((contextValue: ValueContextState) => ({
                ...contextValue,
                state,
            }));
        }, [state]);
    
        return <ValueContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</ValueContext.Provider>;
    };
    
    function getDefaultState(): ValueState {
        return {
            value: null,
        };
    }
    
    type Props = {
        children: React.ReactNode;
    };
```

customHook

```
export const useValues = () => {
    const { state, dispatch } = useContext(ValueContext);

    const setValue = useCallback(
        (value: string | null) => {
         console.log("dispatch") // getting called once!
            dispatch({
                type: AcionType.SetValue,
                value: value,
            });
        },
        [dispatch],
    );

    return {
        value: state.value,
        setValue: setValue,
    };
};
```

Using Provider

```
<Routes>
            <Route
                index
                element={
                    <ValueProvider>
                        <Values />
                    </ValueProvider>
                }
            />
        </Routes>
```

making dispatch

```
 export const Value = () => {
        const { setValue } = useValues();
        return <InputComponent onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />;
    };
```

Comment: Could this be it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846289/why-is-my-react-component-is-rendering-twice ? It is quite common reason for such problems. You can use the most upvoted answer to test it out.

Comment: I cant believe it.
I sat loosely 3 days at the measures. Should that be turned off? Is it good

Comment: Well, there is a debate whether it should be turned off or not. In my view it is fine to be kept on if you can be sure that the double render problem is caused by that 'extra caution measure'. Its intention is good but it can cause confusion. So, try taking it off to see if it fixes your problem. If it does, great. Then you know there is nothing else wrong with it. Double render only happens in dev environment, so when running it in production mode, this shouldn't happen anymore if it was because of this extra measure. So, take it off, see if it works and put it back on in my opinion.

Comment: Could you please take a look here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73004815/17682036 Do you know why the functional solution is not working? Hope it is not to random

Comment: @axordahaxor i completely reformulated my question

Comment: Would you mind building a code sandbox(https://codesandbox.io) that matches exactly your situation right now? So that it shows the error and has all the logging and everything in place to reproduce the problem? I'm sure me and other people would like to see it and tinker with it :)

Comment: Also, this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62336340/cannot-update-a-component-while-rendering-a-different-component-warning came up while searching for your error and it could help resolve it. Again two of the most common upvoted answers could help you in the problem.

Comment: Many Thanks. Yes, I already know the post. He doesn't help me. I don't know if it's react 16. I only get the error with the debugger. I can try to show the logic there, but it will take some time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246571/discussion-between-maxfromgermany-and-axordahaxor).